# Sql query for aggregation

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, aggregation

Let consider the below table structure

```
Product    Year   Month Price

A         2011      01   23

A         2011      02   34
```

.......

.....

```
A       2011      12    54   
B       2011      01   13

B       2011      02   12
```

.......

.....

B       2011      12    20

From this table i need to aggregate the value for every 3 months ie..,

```
Product        Year          Month              Price

A              2011          1-3                45

A              2011          4-6                23

A              2011          7-9                45

A              2011          10-12              16
```

A              2012          1-3                12
.......
.......

Can anybody tell me how to do this calculation using sql query...
Thanks in Advance !!!

Comment: Month and Year are varchar()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. Use `Case statement` to group the month Quarter wise then find the `sum of price`

```
SELECT product,
       [year],
       CASE
         WHEN ( [month] ) IN( '01', '02', '03' ) THEN '1-3'
         WHEN ( [month] ) IN( '04', '05', '06' ) THEN '4-6'
         WHEN ( [month] ) IN( '07', '08', '09' ) THEN '7-9'
         WHEN ( [month] ) IN( '10', '11', '12' ) THEN '10-12'
       END [Month],
       Sum(Price)
FROM   tablename
GROUP  BY product,
          [year],
          CASE
            WHEN ( [month] ) IN( '01', '02', '03' ) THEN '1-3'
            WHEN ( [month] ) IN( '04', '05', '06' ) THEN '4-6'
            WHEN ( [month] ) IN( '07', '08', '09' ) THEN '7-9'
            WHEN ( [month] ) IN( '10', '11', '12' ) THEN '10-12'
          END
```

**Note :** By looking at your `month` data it looks like its a `varchar` column but you can change it to **[TINYINT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms187745.aspx)**

Answer (score 0):

Try using `CASE` in `GROUP BY` clause:

```
...
GROUR BY [Year], CASE WHEN Month in (1,2,3) THEN '1-3'
                      WHEN Month in (4,5,6) THEN '4-6'
                  ...
                 END
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering `Month` is stored as `varchar()`, you can write as:

```
Select Product,
       Year,
       [MonthRange] as [Month],
       Sum(Price)
From (
select Product,
       Year,
       case when Month in ('01','02','03') then '[1-3]'
            when Month in ('04','05','06') then '[4-6]'
            when Month in ('07','08','09') then '[7-9]'
            when Month in ('10','11','12') then '[10-12]'
       end as [MonthRange],
       Price
from @test) as T
Group by Product,Year,[MonthRange]
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://rextester.com/KKCAI5958)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

> select Product, [year], case when [month] between 1 and 3 then '01-03' else case when [month] between 4 and 6 then '04-06' else case when [month] between 7 and 9 then '07-09' else  '10-12' end end end, sum([price])
>
> from Table1
>
> group by Product, [year], case when [month] between 1 and 3 then '01-03' else case when [month] between 4 and 6 then '04-06' else case when [month] between 7 and 9 then '07-09' else  '10-12' end end end

Above sql query will give you the required results, if you don not use leading zeros which I used in month labels then you will not get result sorted by month.

Answer (score 0):

Use this query.

```
CREATE table #test
(
    product VARCHAR(10),
    year int, 
    month int, 
    price int
)

INSERT INTO #test
SELECT 'A', 2011, 01, 23 UNION
SELECT 'A', 2011, 02, 65 UNION
SELECT 'A', 2011, 03, 45 UNION
SELECT 'B', 2011, 04, 34 UNION
SELECT 'B', 2011, 05, 67 UNION
SELECT 'B', 2011, 06, 34 UNION
SELECT 'B', 2011, 07, 87 UNION
SELECT 'B', 2011, 08, 2 UNION
SELECT 'B', 2011, 09, 345 UNION
SELECT 'B', 2011, 10, 9 UNION
SELECT 'B', 2011, 11, 293 UNION
SELECT 'B', 2011, 12, 23 

    SELECT product, [year], [MONTH], SUM(price)
    FROM
    (

    SELECT product,  [year], CASE WHEN [MONTH] IN (01,02,03) THEN '1-3'
                               WHEN [MONTH] IN (04,05,06) THEN '4-6'
                               WHEN [MONTH] IN (07,08,09) THEN '7-9'
                               WHEN [MONTH] IN (10, 11, 12) THEN '10-12'
                         END AS [Month],    
            price
        FROm #Test
    )AS A
    group BY product, [year], [Month]
```